# truncate md5 hash to 20 characters?

Tags: hash, md5

Is it possible to count how unique it will be if md5hash email addresses and truncate hash to 20 characters ?
Does it matter if truncating beginning or ending? 
It will be used as samaccountname in AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of possible unique results will be reduced from `2^128` (32 characters * 4 bits) to `2^80` (20 characters * 4 bits).

Truncating the result at any point (beginning, middle or end) won't affect the entropy, only increasing the possibility of a collision. At `2^80` possibilities you shouldn't have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

What would happen in the event of a collision? You would probably be safe to assume that adversaries would be able to create two e-mail addresses that hash to the same value under MD5.

If this is a concern, you may want to consider an alternative scheme (like an HMAC), which would be much harder to create a collision for, especially without knowledge of the HMAC key.